# Why is my travis build not starting?

Tags: travis-ci

Why have builds 21 and 22 in https://travis-ci.org/tbsalling/aismessages/builds not started to build?

Comment: Looks like build 21 is running. Travis builds can sometimes take some time to start.

Comment: Yes - you're right. It waited almost a full day before it started!

Comment: As of june 15 2021 https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022714/8608146

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everything worked fine. Patience is the key. It took several hours (almost a full day) before travis started on the jobs.

Comment: How long? A day? Oh dear, what a disappointment I've chosen it for my new project.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time it happens because of any error in your travis.yml file.

So first check your travis yaml file syntax. You can use Yamllint for this.

```
brew install yamllint
```

Or you can use pip

```
pip install yamllint
```

Comment: But not in this case. I did not change travis.yml to make the builds run.

Answer (score 3):

All builds that used travis-cli.org after June 15th, 2021 will no longer work.

Here is the message from Travis Cli, when logged in using `travis-ci.org`:

> Since June 15th, 2021, the building on travis-ci.org is ceased. Please use travis-ci.com from now on."

Comment: Hmm, looks like there's no free version any more, travis-ci.com only has 30 day free trial...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the build was not starting because Travis couldn't find my .travis.yml config file, because it was not in my root folder.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth checking if your .travis.yml file exists or if it does not contain github conflict.

Answer (score 1):

#### use .yml instead of .yaml

I faced this when travis wasn't able to find my travis yaml file in the root. Here is how to possible fix:

- Just change the file name .travis.yaml to .travis.yml and it starts building.
- Also, Make sure your `.travis.yml` file is in root directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I simply forgot to include `sudo` in my command. Checking .travis.yaml with yamllint gave me a hint as to what the problem was since it had an error at the line where the missing sudo was. What threw me off was that it did not explicitly say that the error would break the file. For example, other errors that were also present in my file were `trailing spaces  (trailing-spaces)` and `line too long (82 > 80 characters)`. And Travis stills runs when the latter two errors are there.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me due to wrong indentation in ".travis.yml" file. You may check and spot it by yamllint tool.